# Pointing a subdomain to Github Pages

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, github

I set up an Octopress blog on Github Pages at myusername.github.com. I now want blog.myusername.me (which currently has a Wordpress blog set up) to point to this Octopress blog.

So I followed the instructions [here](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/#custom_domains) on setting up a custom domain:

- I ran `echo 'blog.myusername.me' >> source/CNAME` in my Octopress repository, and then ran `rake generate` and `rake deploy` to deploy it to Github.
- I went to Namecheap, and added a new CNAME under my myusername.me domain: "blog -> myusername.github.com -> CNAME".
- Waited a couple hours.

However, now when I go to myusername.github.com, it redirects me to blog.myusername.me (which is my old Wordpress blog), which seems like the inverse of what I want. (Going to blog.myusername.me directly still shows my Wordpress blog.)

I checked http://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/blog.myusername.me and it seems like my DNS has propagated (myusername.github.com shows up in the right-hand side).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If the DNS has started to propagate, you may be facing caching on your computer or ISP's DNS server. I'd wait for a bit, or try either:

- temporarily using a different DNS provider, e.g. [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) or [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) (you may need to restart your browser or OS)
- checking from a computer using a different ISP/DNS server

Good luck.

Comment: +1 Without more info about the situation I think this is the most likely cause. DNS changes take time to propagate. Here's some info on how to clear your local cache in Windows/OSX. http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/ClearingBrowserCache. It may take additional time for the remote DNS servers to update to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set nameservers *and* CNAME records.

Go to Namecheap.com --> Manage Domains and click on the domain you want to manage. Then, go to All Host Records and change the settings to this.
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the your actual domain name it's hard to help, but I would recommend you use [IP Tools](http://www.iptools.com/) to figure out where the DNS is actually pointing.